# Bootstrap Form Horizontal Alignment Errors

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

My textboxes aren't aligning with my form properly at all. I'm using Bootstrap within ASP.NET MVC 4. As you can see I'm using the form-horizontal div but im not sure why my elements are appearing all out of line. How do I get the elements to align with the labels?

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Please enter the Inventory No", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo, new {maxlength = "10", autocomplete = "off"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo)
                <span class="help-block">Inventory No is physically located on the Inventory sticker device on the side of a device.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Please add any keywords", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Tags, new {autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "250"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tags)
                    <span class="help-block">Required: Enter the keywords of your fault description. For emample, Printer, Jammed, Paper and etc. </span>
                </div>
            </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Please enter a description of the fault", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.IncidentDescription, new {maxlength = "90"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentDescription)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would add the `form-control` class to your textboxes and textarea i.e

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Log.InventoryNo, new {maxlength = "10", autocomplete = "off", @class="form-control"})
....
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Tags, new {autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "250", @class="form-control"})
```

See here for more info on form-control:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Secondly you need to add your labels within your column divs like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Please enter a description of the fault", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.IncidentDescription, new {maxlength = "90"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IncidentDescription)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is a simple example here:

http://www.bootply.com/128038