# How to align form inputs with boostrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having some problem aligning input forms with bootstrap in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I have a partial view with two input fields (representing a title and a message for a Post class) and a button, but the inputs won't align properly.

I have a pic on the alignment here:

[image: Alignment]

Does anyone know how to align these properly with bootstrap?

I have tried putting them in separate `<div>s` with the class "form-group", and also in the same `<div>`, but it doesn't fix the problem.

```
@model Post
<form asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Post" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label asp-for="@Model.Title"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.Title" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Message"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.Message" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe this answers can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911713/bootstrap-form-horizontal-alignment-errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388344/incorrect-aligning-of-form-controls-in-asp-mvc-5-and-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can either give all the labels a fixed width in columns by using a class like .col-4, 
this way all of your labels will take the same space no matter if they're smaller, or another good approach would be to use the labels on top of the fields, this way no matter how long is the label text it would fit in

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Putting the class on the labels didn't seem to work. But I agree that it's a quite nice approach to have the labels over the input fields anyways. Is it nice style to have an own div with a form-group class for them aswell? Or can they just "float by themselves" there without a div covering them?

Comment: Official documentation of bootstrap shows this example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ where you place the label and the input inside a div with the `form-group` class and no extra structure needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
  // using Bootstrap4

```
 <form asp-controller="Post" asp-action="Post" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <div class=row>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.Title">Title</label> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Title" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class=row>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.Message">Message</label> 
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Message" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```